# How to Identify Contact as Deceased

Tags: contacts

We have a contact in our database that is now deceased. We would like to maintain their historical records for archival use, but want to ensure that we stop sending mailings.

How do I identify someone in CiviCRM as being deceased?

Answer (score 10):

Inside a contact, under demographics (gender, age, etc.) when you choose "Edit demographics" there's an option for "Contact is deceased".

Comment: bit hidden away!

Answer (score 2):

As well as what RayWright said, if you're using 4.4 or below you might like to try this extension: https://civicrm.org/extensions/show-contact-deceased